# How to Test if row is in matrix?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am looking for a way to return the index of where a particular row resides in matrix.  I can guarantee every row to be unique, as well as the row to always exist in the matrix.  How can I do this in matlab?
For example, Suppose you have a matrix `c`:

```
 c =

   1   2   3
   3   2   1
```

further, you have a matrix `b`:

```
b =

   1   2   3
```

I would like some function `func` where I could call

```
func(b,c)
    1
```

or even just return:

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html). If every row is unique, and all you want is the index, you can get it as follows (replace `~` by `dummy` if you're using Matlab pre-2009b).

```
[~,index] = ismember(b,c,'rows')
```